# POSTFIX - limit send and receive done by user in time interval

Tags: postfix-mta

I am trying to limit the number of send/receive attempt done by my user to postfix server in time unit. Eg, i want the postfix to process each user's connection once in 60s.

As currently, my user keep clicking on the send/receive button in their email client, it can be 10 times just in a sec.

I have tried to use `smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit = 60` but it does not work, postfix still process the user request.

Answer (score 0):

Using Postfix you can only control the users's SENDING patterns (since sending using SMTP, which is what Postfix can handle). The receiving end would be done using some sort of IMAP/POP3 server.

smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit controls the amount of connections per minute (in this case, you're allowing 60 connections/1 Minute)

But what is the actual problem? The usage pattern is fairly normal, this behaviour shouldn't strain your server at all (I'd rather suspect FETCHING to be an issue here, thus an issue with IMAP/POP)...